# CIR model calibration - python

Tags: programming, interest-rates, factor-models

EDIT: or maybe to add, is the below way of calibration better than calculating as:

longer term mean b: average of interest rates

speed of reversion a: ln(1/drift)

volatility σ

---

I am trying to calibrate the CIR model on monthly interval 3 mon t bill rates,
below is my code but I am not sure which approach is better the above one or the below coded approach? ( if the code is correct not sure)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

# Define the CIR model
def cir_model(params, r, dt):
    kappa, theta, sigma = params
    dr = kappa * (theta - r) * dt + sigma * np.sqrt(r) * np.sqrt(dt)
    return dr

# Define the objective function to minimize (sum of squared errors)
def objective_function(params, r):
    dt = 1/12  # Monthly interval
    error = 0
    for n in range(len(r)):
        error_ = r[n] - cir_model(params, r[n], dt)
        error += error_**2
    return error

# Initial parameter guess
initial_params = [0.1, 0.05, 0.1]

# List of interest rates
interest_rates = [0.04, 0.05, 0.04, 0.04, 0.02, 0.05, 0.07]

# Convert interest rates to a NumPy array
interest_rates = np.array(interest_rates)

# Perform parameter calibration
result = minimize(objective_function, initial_params, args=(interest_rates,), method='Nelder-Mead')

# Extract the calibrated parameters
calibrated_params = result.x
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
calibrated_params
```